# Find database calls from a Page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, performance, sql-server-2008

I am using `sql server 2008` and website is in `asp.net 1.1`.

Is there a way to find out **`how many times database has been called from a page`**?

```
What are the stored procedure called from the page?

What are the tables involved in a page load?
```

Please suggest how can i track these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing is to use [SQL profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), which will keep track of every call made to the database.

You may see this article: [SQL SERVER – Introduction to SQL Server 2008 Profiler](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/)

Comment: Thanks..I will run the sql profiler.Just wanted to know, is it going to change anything in database if i run profiler?

Comment: @Learner, no its not going to change any data in the db or anything like that. It will just let you know about all the request/operations made against the database server. You may filter the results based on a particular database